# Foreach doesn't work in php

Tags: php, foreach

I have a code like this:

```
<?php

$kode ["J"]= array (20, C, D, F);
$kode ["K"]= array (50, B, G, U);
$kode ["T"]= array (70, V, W);

function kota ($start, $end){
    if (is_array($kode)) {
        foreach ($kode as $kota => $path){
            if ($kota=$end) {
                for ($i=1; $i < count ($kota); $i++){
                    $jalur=$start.$path[$i];
                }
            }
        }
        return $jalur;
    }
}
$start = "J";
$end = "T";
$hasil=kota ($start, $end);
echo "".$hasil;
?>
```

I want the output to be `J-V-W` 
I don't know what is wrong, can anyone help me? please...

Comment: don't you mean `if($kota==$end)`? (note the double `=`)

Comment: You're not passing the array `$kode` as argument to the function

Comment: The foreach works, but you're using it wrong (passing string instead of array).

Comment: Also `$jalur=$start.$path[$i];` should be `$jalur.=$start.$path[$i];` (note the `.=` which means to append)

Comment: thanks so much for your answer.. i'm newbie in programming, so i dont know lot of things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has lots of issues

1. As others pointed out, in `if ($kota=$end) {`, you are assigning `$end` to `$kota` and always return `true` i.e. the code in the IF clause always execute
2. PHP has function scope. Simply put, variables declared inside a function cannot be used outside, and vice versa. Use parameters to pass your `$kode` into the function.
3. Use of bare strings i.e. `V` and `W` in `$kode ["T"]= array (70, V, W);` and other places. This is highly recommended against, and PHP does warn you about this.
4. As other pointed out, `$jalur=$start.$path[$i];` would overwrite `$jalur` every time. The for-loop outside is meaningless. You would use `.=` the append-to operator. Note that you also need to initialize your variable before using this operator.
5. `$kota` is always a string in your code, because in a `foreach` loop, the variable before `=>` symbol means get the key of the array, and array keys can only be either String or integer. That said, `for ($i=1; $i < count ($kota); $i++){` is meaningless because `count($kota)` cannot be greater than 1 - your for loop actually never runs.
6. This is blatantly meaningless to append a variable with an empty string as in `echo "".$hasil;`

I guess this is what you want.

```
<?php

$kode ["J"] = array (20, 'C', 'D', 'F');
$kode ["K"] = array (50, 'B', 'G', 'U');
$kode ["T"] = array (70, 'V', 'W');

function kota ($kode, $start, $end){
    $jalur = $start;
    if (is_array($kode)) {
        foreach ($kode as $kota => $path){
            if ($kota == $end) {
                for ($i = 1; $i < count($path); ++$i) {
                    $jalur .= '-' . $path[$i];
                }
            }
        }
        return $jalur;
    }
}
$start = "J";
$end = "T";
$hasil = kota($kode, $start, $end);
echo $hasil;
?>
```

This code give you the string which starts with `$start` and all other elements except the first element in `$kode[$end]`

Comment: yea... i just don't know how to write my idea into a code. i just start learning php. thanks so much for ur explanation. that's really help me to learn

Answer (score 4):

### Syntatical errors

Looks like you forgot to use the equality operator `==`

```
if ($kota = $end){ ... }
```

Should be -

```
if ($kota == $end){ ... }
```

By using only one equals sign you are actually *assigning* a value to `$kota`, not *comparing* the value to `$end` as should be done in conditional expressions.

I don't think this is the only thing that is causing trouble here.. but it definitely should be sorted out :)

---

### Variable scope

Another thing I noticed in your code is that you are referencing variables within the `kota` function that were not defined in it's scope. This means that the `$kota` array is not accessible within the `kota` function. You should pass the `$kota` array to the function so that you can use it within scope of the function. [Here is some more info on variable scopes in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

---

### Naming conventions

One final note on your variable name choice... You should possibly think of changing the variable `$kota` or function `kota` so that their names are not identical. This will help improve readability and perhaps prevent some mistakes at 4am when you've been debugging the whole night ;)

Comment: And to add `$kota=$end` will always be true, so your code will go on all the time.

Comment: @dai - the code I posted was originally given by the OP. I was showing which line was problematic...

Answer (score 2):

On the line

```
if ($kota=$end){
```

you are not comparing, but overwriting the value in $kota, and that is always true.

Also the `$kode` is not available in the function scope, try adding it to the parameter list, or using `global` (not advised).

Answer (score 0):

You need to either pass `$kode` into your function as an argument or call `global $kode;` inside your function. I'd recommend the former.

Additionally, `if ($kota=$end)` needs to be `if ($kota==$end)` as others have mentioned.

Comment: yeah.. i didn't notice. ^.^'a

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, that `$jalur=$start;` is on the correct place, but this script gives what you want:

```
<?php

$kode ["J"]= array (20, 'C', 'D', 'F');
$kode ["K"]= array (50, 'B', 'G', 'U');
$kode ["T"]= array (70, 'V', 'W');

function kota ($start, $end){
      global $kode;

      if(is_array($kode)){

            foreach ($kode as $kota => $path){

                  if ($kota == $end){
                        $jalur=$start;
                        for ($i=1; $i < count ($path); $i++){
                              $jalur .= "-" . $path[$i];
                        }
                  }
            }
            return $jalur;
      }
}
$start  = "J";
$end    = "T";
$hasil=kota ($start, $end);
echo $hasil;
?>
```

Comment: you are right.. $jalur=$start is not in the correct place. thanks so much.. ^_^

Comment: @Anna ok, tell me where it should be. I'll fix my answer and we'll close the question.

Comment: no.. it's not like that.. this program is just a simulation. $start can be anything. so, it doesn't matter